# Multiple Excel file in sprint boot

Tags: java, excel, spring-boot, apache-poi

[image]IS there the way to create **multiple excel file instead of multiple worksheets** through spring boot?
I have been using apache poi for generation of excel.

```
@GetMapping("/export/excel")
    public void exportToExcel(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
        String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
        String headervalue = "attachment; filename=Customer.xlsx";
        response.setHeader(headerKey, headervalue);
        List<cusEntity> data1= customerRepo.fetchEmailData();
        UserExcelExporter exp = new UserExcelExporter(data1);
        exp.export(response);
}
```

---

```
public class UserExcelExporter {
    private XSSFWorkbook workbook;
    private XSSFSheet sheet;
    private List<EmailDataEntity> listClients;

public UserExcelExporter(List<cusEntity> listClients) {
    this.listClients=listClients;
    workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
}

private void createCell(Row row, int columnCount, Object value, CellStyle style) {
    sheet.autoSizeColumn(columnCount);
    Cell cell=row.createCell(columnCount);
    if(value instanceof Long) {
        cell.setCellValue((Long) value);
    }else if(value instanceof Integer) {
        cell.setCellValue((Integer) value);
    }else if(value instanceof Boolean) {
        cell.setCellValue((Boolean) value);
    }else {
        cell.setCellValue((String) value);
    }
    cell.setCellStyle(style);
}

private void writeHeaderLine(String iteration) {
        sheet = workbook.createSheet("Report");
        Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
        CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
        style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
        createCell(row,0,"Trust & Agency Service",style);
        sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(0,0,0,6));
        font.setFontHeightInPoints((short)(10));
    }

private void writeDataLines() {
    int rowCount=1;
    CellStyle style=workbook.createCellStyle();
    XSSFFont font=workbook.createFont();
    font.setFontHeight(14);
    style.setFont(font);
    for(cusEntity client:listClients) {
        Row row=sheet.createRow(rowCount++);
        int columnCount=0;
        createCell(row, columnCount++, client.getname(), style);
    }
}

public void export(HttpServletResponse response,String iteration) throws IOException{
    writeHeaderLine(iteration);
    writeDataLines();
    ServletOutputStream outputStream=response.getOutputStream();
    workbook.write(outputStream);
    workbook.close();
    outputStream.close();
}
```

}

When i try to repeat the code of exp.export(response) , it gives me the 1 excel and for the next excel it says  The workbook already contains a sheet named 'Report'.
I thought that if it created 2 excel then having the same worksheet name should not have been the issue .
But seems like its trying to create another sheet instead of another excel .
Correct me if I am wrong .

Thanks Team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I did it was by changing the output stream:
And passing fileName from the HomeController

```
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format("C:\\Users\\kasis\\ExcelFolder\\%s.xlsx",fileName));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the point here is that you're mixing concepts.

The excel file is actually the workbook, while the sheet here is just the tab inside the excel file.

So if you want a new excel file, you must create a new workbook.

And each workbook can contain several sheets (tabs), but each one must have a unique name (that's why it does not allow another sheet using the same name in the same file)

Comment: What if I do ,
{..//something, 
exp.export(response);
exp.export(response);
}
To generate 2 excel
@shikida

Comment: doesn't it create 2 workbook ?IF i repeat exp.export(response) ?

Comment: @KasisShrestha the code you've provided does not show exactly where the workbook is being created, but I bet it's in the UserExcelExporter(data1) constructor. If it's so, calling the export() method twice won't create two different excel files. But maybe, if you call the constructor twice, it will do the trick. We can only tell inspecting the whole UserExcelExporter class.

Comment: Edited the Code . 
Can you have a look ?
Appreciated the effort .

Comment: @KasisShrestha as we can see now, a new excel file is created at workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); -- so I think you need to call new UserExcelExporter(data1) for each new excel file you want to generate

Comment: added the screenshot . 
it created only 1 excel though the constructor is being called twice

Comment: if you want to generate 2 excel files in the same request, then you must of declare two attachments in the response, each one with a different name

Comment: tried it didn't work. Seems like we need to create the zip for such case scenario when we want multiple excel